# Importing values from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I can't import values values from SQL Server to Excel. Can someone please help:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub ConnectDB()

    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=ServerName; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=MyDB;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
End Sub
Public Sub ExportDataToDB()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    ConnectDB
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "select t.col1, t.col2 from Table t"

    rs.Open strSql, oConn

    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    CloseDBConn
End Sub

Private Sub CloseDBConn()
    oConn.Close
End Sub
```

Connection is successful. No errors. Query is not empty, but nothing is returned into sheet.

Comment: Is your table-name really `Table`?

Comment: How do you determine if the query is not empty? What would `?rs.RecordCount` return? Also might be worth checking if `Sheet1` belongs to where you think belongs.

Comment: @FunThomas, does that matter what table name is?

Comment: Where are you declaring `Sheet1`?

Comment: @VictorK, record count returns -1

Comment: @braX, I'm not declaring Sheet1 anywhere, it's just Sheet1 of excel. It's there

Comment: @Sher: No, as long as the name is correct - but I think the name `table` is a reserved word and cannot be used as table name. So I assume that your SQL statement is wrong. However, that should lead to a runtime error.

Comment: that's not how it works.

Comment: @FunThomas, I just coded that name as Table, so that things are clear. Actually its name is other. And query returns 22 rows when I run it in SSMS

Comment: @braX, Can you please help me review it?

Comment: Not if you dont declare Sheet1.

Comment: @braX, how I should declare it? It's like there. Are they declared at all?

Comment: @Sher I believe that the issue might be with the `RecordSet` itself if it returns you a negative `RecordCount`. Possibly you should look into `CursorType` property (I would use `adOpenStatic`if you are just reading the values to spreadhseet)

Comment: @brax: No, it's allowed to access a sheet by it's `CodeName`.

Comment: @VictorK, That helped. Thanks. adOpenStatic issue. Would you mind post your solution?

Comment: @Sher I am glad it helped, I will post it in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you would like to just read a set of records from the database, such as writing current state of the records to the worksheet you should specify `CursorType` property of the `ADODB.RecordSet` as `adOpenStatic`
Here is the link to Microsoft documention of it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/types-of-cursors-ado